# How to grab random videos to play under certain conditions

Tags: java, android

My goal is to have multiple mp4's stores in different folders on a server.  I want to grab one of the videos from the folder when a certain condition is met.  How would I grab a random video file from a particular folder?  Here is the code I have written:

```
public static Uri getVideoPath(String cond){
  Uri tempPath;

  if((cond.equals("01"))||(cond.equals("02"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/sunny/");
  }else if((cond.equals("03"))||(cond.equals("04"))|| (cond.equals("05"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/some_sun/");
  }else if((cond.equals("06"))||(cond.equals("07"))||(cond.equals("08"))||
    (cond.equals("36"))||(cond.equals("37"))||(cond.equals("38"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/cloudy/");
  }else if((cond.equals("09"))||(cond.equals("10"))||(cond.equals("27"))||(cond.equals("28"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/light_gray/");
  }else if(cond.equals("11")){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/fog/");
  }else if((cond.equals("12"))||(cond.equals("13"))|| (cond.equals("14"))||
    (cond.equals("39"))||(cond.equals("40"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/showers/");
  }else if((cond.equals("15"))||(cond.equals("16"))|| (cond.equals("17"))||
    (cond.equals("40"))||(cond.equals("41"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/thunderstorms/");
  }else if(cond.equals("18")){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/rain/");
  }else if((cond.equals("19"))||(cond.equals("20"))|| (cond.equals("21"))||(cond.equals("43"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/flurries/");
  }else if((cond.equals("22"))||(cond.equals("23"))||(cond.equals("44"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/snow/");
  }else if((cond.equals("24"))||(cond.equals("25"))|| (cond.equals("26"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/ice/");
  }else if(cond.equals("29")){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/rain_and_snow/");
  }else if(cond.equals("30")){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/hot/");
  }else if(cond.equals("31")){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/cold/");
  }else if(cond.equals("32")){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/windy/");
  }else if((cond.equals("33"))||(cond.equals("34"))||(cond.equals("35"))){
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/clear/");
  }else{
   tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/clear/");
  }   
  return tempPath;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
File dir = new File(getVideoPath(condition));
Random gen = new Random();

File[] videos = dir.listFiles();

int random_index = gen.nextInt(videos.length);

return videos[random_index];
```

Comment: I tried this and posted my code as an "answer" of my own.  I don't know if this is the correct way to repost, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I may be back for more later, but for now I am good to go.

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of the cascaded if-else, create a [HashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and `put` each combination of condition and path. Then, retrieval is simply:

```
public static Uri getVideoPath(String cond){
  Uri tempPath = map.get(condition);
  if (tempPath == null) tempPath = Uri.parse("http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/clear/");
  return tempPath;
}
```

You can't get a directory listing using [File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)'s `listFiles()` as that only work on local files. You'll have to [open the URL and read](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)  the directory listing. Assuming your server supports PHP, you'll probably be better off adding an `index.php` that simply returns a list of files in text/plain. Once you have that loaded into an array, the rest of [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380521/patrick)'s code will do the trick.

Comment: I'm actually developing this on Android platform.  Does this change any of your suggestions?

Comment: Never mind...I get what you're saying and am working on implementing the HashMap now.